# How to find or log currently running test in MSTEST.exe

Tags: crash, mstest

We have a build process including unittest launched via mstest.exe. Sometimes some unittest get stuck, a messagebox or send error dialog is stuck or entire process crashes. I don't know how to find which of tests is the bad one.

Is there any way how to find what is the name of currently running test in case the unittest is stuck?

Is there a way how to find the name of unittest which was runned the last time?

I don't want to set up timeout for every single test, because I am not sure, what is the suitable timeout.

A nice solution for me could be to log when unittests start a when finish. I could find what is the last logged unittest. Is there a way to log it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TestContext.TestName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.testname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it:

```
/// Use this method to run code before running each test.
[TestInitialize()]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    YourLogger.LogFormat("Run test {0}", this.TestContext.TestName);
}

/// Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
    YourLogger.LogFormat("Test {0} is done", this.TestContext.TestName);
}
```

Comment: You can create a base class that implements this logging, have a look at this blog article: [Using a Base Class for your Unit Test Classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2008/05/16/using-a-base-class-for-your-unit-test-classes.aspx)